# Rules for checking rendered-attribute for JSF2 custom-component

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component, rendered-attribute

I have a simple custom-component like this which does not respect the attribute *rendered*.

```
@FacesComponent("my.OutputText")
public class OutputText extends UIPanel
{   
  @Override public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {...}
  @Override public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {...}
}
```

Of course, I can check for the attribute *rendered* in both methods, add `@Override public boolean getRendersChildren()` and also check for the *rendered* attribute and then simple not render the children in `encodeChildren`.

But what is the recommended rule for implementing this common feature?

Answer (score 1):

That's already described in javadoc of [`UIComponent` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html).

To take [`encodeBegin()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeBegin%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) as an example:

> ### encodeBegin
>
> ```
> public abstract void encodeBegin(FacesContext context)
>                      throws java.io.IOException
> ```
>
> If our `rendered` property is `true`, render the beginning of the current state of this `UIComponent` to the response contained in the specified FacesContext. Call [`pushComponentToEL(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,javax.faces.component.UIComponent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#pushComponentToEL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29). Call [`Application.publishEvent(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#publishEvent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29), passing [`PreRenderComponentEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PreRenderComponentEvent.html)`.class` as the first argument and the component instance to be rendered as the second argument.
>
> If a `Renderer` is associated with this `UIComponent`, the actual encoding will be delegated to `Renderer#encodeBegin(FacesContext, UIComponent)`.
>
> If our rendered property is `false`, call [`pushComponentToEL(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,javax.faces.component.UIComponent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#pushComponentToEL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) and return immediately.

And [`getRendersChildren()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getRendersChildren%28%29):

> ### getRendersChildren
>
> ```
> public abstract boolean getRendersChildren()
> ```
>
> Return a flag indicating whether this component is responsible for rendering its child components. The default implementation in `UIComponentBase#getRendersChildren` tries to find the renderer for this component. If it does, it calls `Renderer#getRendersChildren` and returns the result. If it doesn't, it returns `false`. As of version 1.2 of the JavaServer Faces Specification, component authors are encouraged to return `true` from this method and rely on `UIComponentBase#encodeChildren`.

Note the last statement. Here's the one for [`UIComponent#encodeChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeChildren%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29):

> ### encodeChildren
>
> ```
> public abstract void encodeChildren(FacesContext context)
>                          throws java.io.IOException
> ```
>
> If our `rendered` property is `true`, render the child `UIComponents` of this `UIComponent`. This method will only be called if the `rendersChildren` property is `true`.
>
> If a `Renderer` is associated with this `UIComponent`, the actual encoding will be delegated to `Renderer#encodeChildren(FacesContext, UIComponent)`. If no `Renderer` is associated with this `UIComponent`, iterate over each of the children of this component and call `encodeAll(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)`.

Note that [`UIComponentBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html) has them already implemented. If you have overridden a method, then you'd need to follow exactly the same rules or perhaps make use of `super.encodeXxx()` if possible. If you don't have `encodeChildren()` overridden, then you don't need to do so anyway.